# A way to refer to a set as a whole

Tags: terminology

I am not a specialist in databases, and I only need to clarify a terminological question that I have.

Assume we have a table containing the field F. F gets its values from the set S, a collection of values of a certain type. (Let's imagine that the elements of S are characters.) Is there a common way to refer to S as a whole? Something like the **alphabet of F** or the **inventory of F**.

Comment: Do you mean the set of possible (allowed) values, or the set of actually used values (in that particular column of the table)?

Answer (score 4):

It's called a [*domain*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribute_domain). And there are no "fields" in tables; there are columns.